# How to center a sign in a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I want to center the sign for the node in the middle. How do I do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{ remember picture,
    SYMBOLI/.style = {rectangle,
    draw,
    semithick,
    align=center,
    label={below:#1},
    label={center:\usebox\SymbolIBox},
    minimum size=0.5cm
   },
}

\newsavebox\SymbolIBox
\savebox\SymbolIBox{%
\tikz\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,-0.15)--(-0.05,-0.15)--(0.05,0.15)--(0.15,0.15);%
}

\tikzset{ remember picture,
    SYMBOLII/.style = {rectangle,
    draw,
    semithick,
    align=center,
    label={below:#1},
    label={center:\usebox\SymbolIIBox},
    minimum size=0.5cm
    },
}

\newsavebox\SymbolIIBox
\savebox\SymbolIIBox{%
\tikz\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,-0.15)--(-0.15,0.15)--(-0.15,0.05)--(0.15,-0.05)--(0.15,-0.15)--(0.15,0.15);
}

\tikzset{ remember picture,
    SYMBOLIII/.style = {rectangle,
    draw,
    semithick,
    align=center,
    label={below:#1},
    label={center:\usebox\SymbolIIIBox},
    minimum size=0.5cm
   },
}

\newsavebox\SymbolIIIBox
\savebox\SymbolIIIBox{%
\tikz\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,0)--(0,0.15)--(0.15,0)--(-0.15,0);%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[SYMBOLI] {};
                \node[SYMBOLII,fill=cyan] at (2,0) {};
                \node[SYMBOLIII,fill=magenta] at (4,0) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Signs}
        \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need a sledgehammer like TiKZ for that? A simple `\fcolorbox`  can do it.

Comment: How would I do it with \fcolorbox?

Comment: Simply, say, `\fcolorbox{black}{red}{Symbol}`. You  might have to add an invisible rule if you want to ensure a square frame (depending on the symbol inside). See `§2.6.2, Colored boxes`, in the documentation of `xcolor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make symbols with TikZ, it is preferable to use the `pic` that have been created by Till Tantau for this purpose. In the manual, read the section `Pics: Small Pictures on Paths`.
Then, to create the symbols, it is easier to use **relative coordinates** instead of absolute coordinates. Relative coordinates *(marked with `--++` or `++`)* indicate the displacement from the previous point. The code is more readable.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{SYMBOLI/.pic={%
\draw [pic actions,line width=.7pt](-.25,-.25)rectangle(.25,.25);
\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,-0.15)--++(0.1,0)--++(0.1,0.3)--++(0.1,0);%
}}

\tikzset{SYMBOLII/.pic={%
\draw [pic actions,line width=.7pt](-.25,-.25)rectangle(.25,.25);
\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,-0.15)--++(0,0.3)++(0,-0.1)--++(0.3,-0.1)++(0,-0.1)--++(0,0.3);
}}

\tikzset{SYMBOLIII/.pic={%
\draw [pic actions,line width=.7pt](-.25,-.25)rectangle(.25,.25);
\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.15,-.085)--++(0.15,.15)--++(0.15,-.15)--++(-0.3,0);%
}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pic at (0,0)  {SYMBOLI};
                \pic[fill=cyan] at (2,0) {SYMBOLII};
                \pic[fill=magenta] at (4,0) {SYMBOLIII};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Signs}
        \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I get an error, "I don't know the key SYMBOLII" and then it ignores it when attempting for symbol2

Comment: Strange, from my side, there's no error. What engine do you compile with? PdfLaTeX? LaTeX? LuaLaTeX ? Another one?

Comment: I am using pdflatex

Comment: It works as a stand alone so it's probably my project which is having issues with the changes

Comment: I am dependent on using this structure
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[SYMBOLI] {};
  \node[SYMBOLII,fill=cyan] at (2,0) {};
  \node[SYMBOLIII,fill=magenta] at (4,0) {};
 \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Why can't you use `pic`?

Comment: Don't know at the moment. I am investigating